# Implication / Interpretation of long term equilibrium VECM

Tags: time-series, predictive-models, finance, causality

I want to test the influence of exchange rates on a price index and struggle with the interpretations. My variables are I(1)

First, I ran an OLS on first differenced variables which indicated a negative short term relation between FX and PI.  Then, I tested it on co-integration and constructed a VECM.

My VECM suggests that there is a long term equilibrium with a speed of adjustment of 50% per period but no short term effect.

Both of my models are robust.

**So, what is the implication of my VECM finding?**

Does a long term equilibrium mean that, in the long-run, FX will not be able to influence the price index, since these variables always rebalance back to equilibrium?

Comment: It depends on the nature of the adjustment you find in VECM. Either the exchange rates adjust towards a price index, or the price index adjusts towards the exchange rate, or both at once. The economic conclusions will be pretty different in those three cases. To answer your last question, FX will not be able to influence the price index *if* FX adjusts towards the price index but the price index does not adjust towards FX. Then the price index is driving the system in the long run. If not, the statement is not correct.